# How to apply weblogic server (10.3.6) security roles to SCA EJB

Tags: security, ejb, weblogic, sca

I want to apply weblogic security roles to SCA service while is exposed as EJB. Please help me int his. We are using weblogic 10.3.6 server.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you referenced the information Oracle provides? https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/how_to_use_security_policies_i

Comment: Yes @better_use_mkstemp, I have tried it. So far I have come to know that Security policy can be applied on Webservice. But as per following link, Policies cannot be applied on EJB. [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/doc.1111/e15511/overview.htm#BABIFCEA) . I know that Weblogic roles can be applied on EJB by configuring the same in ejb-jar.xml(or through annotations). Since in my case, There are no EJBs but SCA which is exposed a EJB, I am unable to find a way to apply security roles to it.